# TFS 2013 and SQL Server 2014 Version Conflict

Tags: sql-server, tfs

Trying to install TFS 2013 using Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (X64), not CTP.  But I get error...

TF255146: Team Foundation Server requires SQL Server 2012 SP1 (11.00.3000) or greater.  The SQL Server instance XXX you supplied is version 12.0.2000.8.

Has anyone experienced it?  Microsoft documentation clearly states SQL 2014 is supported.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this is correct, SQL Server 2014 is supported, but only with TFS 2013 Update 2, which was released a couple of days ago.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2014/04/02/tfs-2013-2-update-2-released.aspx

Comment: only Microsoft consistently comes out with products that don't work.  Thanks Microsoft for wasting another three hours of my life!  Luckily dean knows what's going on over there.

Answer (score 2):

Also, If you do install TFS 2013.3 (Update 2) with SQLServer 2014   There is a nasty performance issue with all of the work item functionality in the web access. Microsoft has not put a fix out  yet . There is a document with a workaround , but its difficult to find ; the way its written it only addresses "Upgrades".

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2953452